# Different browser behaviour between hyperlink click and type URL in browser's address bar

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I have, inside an HTML page, this link:

```
https://view-awesome-table.com/-L1O9CTIgXRslCew09ji/view?filterA=Citrus
```

This is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="https://view-awesome-table.com/-L1O9CTIgXRslCew09ji/view?filterA=Citrus" target="_blank">
     <button type = "button"> BUTTON 2 </ button>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on it, in the page that opens the parameters (`?FilterA=Citrus`) have no effect.

But if I copy and paste the same link in the browser's address bar, the parameters take effect.

I do not understand these different results. **The result that I would like is that clicking the link will have the same effect as entering the URL in the address bar of the browser.** Can someone help me understand?

Comment: `referer` (also depends on how the site works)

Comment: ([Previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48235593/1591669), got closed, and then edited by OP)

Comment: Are you aware that `button` inside `a` is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Eihter u use anchor tag or button tag ,

See this post: [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)

use anchor tag like bellow and use css to as like button .

```css
.btn{
    padding: 6px 41px;
    font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.71429
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    
  }
```

```html
<a href="https://view-awesome-table.com/-L1O9CTIgXRslCew09ji/view?filterA=Citrus" target="_blank" class="btn" > BUTTON 2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Axiom_shuvo.

I tried to follow your advice but unfortunately the result does not change. :-(

Comment: there is nothing in my code ,maybe js/jquery prevent the click event. have any code like on click anchor e.preventDefault(); ???????