# Mozilla cannot read my button with "href"

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I created my portfolio but unfortunately I cannot use
a button properly. What did I wrong?

On Chrome it does work pretty well!

friendly regard

```html
<button><a href="portfolio.html">Check Portfolio</a></button>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `<a>` isn't a valid child element of `<button>` (or vice versa).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5#6393863

Comment: Further, there's no reason to have this markup.  These two elements serve two different purposes: A `<button>` provides a _form button_.  An `<a>` provides a link / anchor.  If you want the appearance of a button, then simply apply a style to your link using classes or similar: `<a class="button">` with some styles: `a.button {display: inline-block; padding: 5px 10px; text-decoration: none; background: blue; color: white; ....etc }`

Answer (score 2):

The proper method to implement this is to stick the button inside of a form with `method="get"` and an action attribute with the site you are linking to.

You can also use JavaScript to set an event handler on the click event of the button.

Also, you can use CSS to make an anchor tag look like a button.

The one route NOT to go is wrapping a `button` in an `a` or vice-versa. It's not proper HTML.

Answer (score 0):

if you use an A tag, you stick the button inside it also, you should use the full url, unless its in the current directory the webpage is in. For example:

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com"><button> Click Here to Google! </button></a>
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot! But do you always have to write full URL, even if you use for your own site?

Comment: if its on the site itself, you can just put the file name in the href if its in the same directory. Some hosting servers need "/filename.html" instead of "filename.html" because of its path settings.

Comment: This solution is wrong: this is **NOT** valid HTML5. See the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: there are several ways to make a button link @Dexter. you can use the java window location with the onclick attribute, if you want to use the html5 button formaction attribute (seems clumsy to have to put form tags around a button so the form attribute works, but ok)