# Creating button inside an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I am building a retail website.  In my product list page, I'm listing each product as a block (3 blocks per row).  Inside each block, I want to show details like name, price, sale price, etc.  I also want an "Add to Cart" button inside each block where if the user clicks on it, I will use a JS function to add the product to the cart.  I want the entire block to be clickable and take the user to the product detail page when clicked.  I have an anchor tag around the entire block.

My problem is when a user clicks on the Add to Cart button, it adds the item to the cart via JS, but then the anchor tag fires and takes the user to the details page.  What's the best way to handle this?

I can move the Add to Cart button out of the block but I'd rather not as there is a border around the block.

Comment: refer this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both users who commented.  Although the answer was slightly different for me, with their help, I got pointed in the right direction and was able to figure it out from there.  Here is my solution:

Add to Cart

// Adds an item to the shopping cart
    function addToCart(productId, price) {
        ...

        addProductToCart(...);
    }

    $("span .button").click(function (e) {
        // Keep the anchor tag from firing when the user clicks on 
        return false;
    });

Answer (score 0):

You want to prevent the click event from firing on the ancestor of your button, you might also say: stop it from propagation up the DOM tree.

This can be achieved via `Event.prototype.stopPropagation`:

Run the code snippet, then click the link / button. Notice how clicking the button does not fire click events on the anchor.

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector('[data-anchor]');
var button = document.querySelector('[data-button]');

anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('anchor clicked');
});

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('button clicked');
});
```

```html
<a href="#" data-anchor>
  <div>Parent content</div>
  <button type="button" data-button>Button</button>
</a>
```