# When a button is clicked (click) event should execute after <a href> event

Tags: javascript, html, angular

When I click a button in my Angular page it should execute the `a href` tag first and then execute the buttons onClick function.

```
<button (click)="invokeFun()"><a href="mylink.com?state=take-back-to-my-link.com">Link</a> </button>
```

But when I use this code, It takes me to the link and brings me back but onClick function is not invoked.

when I checked Chrome Inspector, I got this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError : invokeFun is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

However, when I use onClick separately, it works.

Comment: Pretty random what I will say, but what if a tag was outside the button tag? Not sure if this is even a thing, just a random though.

Comment: I have to execute both one after another on a single click. a tag link provides me with a token and onClick function uses that token

Comment: One fast way to solve this is to only have a button with an onclick function, in that function make an ajax request using jquery (instead of your a tag) and then with the data received call the invoceFun() function.

Comment: Process flow doesn't make sense. If you leave current page completely current page starts all over when you come back. There is no event stored in persistence

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, you are right! but the problem is the token expires soon and the form is lengthy and takes time to fill up. So I thought of saving a form state and reutilizing the form after getting the token.

Comment: Don't do this! It is invalid HTML : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button. Note : Permitted content Phrasing content but there must be no Interactive content.

Comment: Thank you everyone, for your input, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't valid HTML5 according to the HTML5 Spec Document from [W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element):
and [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/2585074)

change your code like this 
HTML:

```
<button (click)="invokeFun()">Link</button>
```

In Compoent :

```
invokeFun(){
    window.location.href = 'mylink.com?state=take-back-to-my-link.com';
}
```