# CSS changed due to the Angular "interpolation"

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm having a strange display of a page when I add an interpolation to generate the code I want (Angular).

static way : display ok ; when using the tag I created, it's not, as you can

[see on this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OaoN.png).

I use Bootstrap on node.js project with Angular.
The  code is :

```
  <ul id="listEvents" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts" *ngIf="isMultipleEvents()">
    <app-event-item  *ngFor="let event of events"
    [hashtag] = "event.hashtag"></app-event-item>
      <li>
          <a href="#">
              <div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">#SCS2018</button>
              </div>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">
              <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">#WKSH2019</button>
              </div>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
          <a class="text-center" href="#">
              <strong>Mes paramètres</strong>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

and the event-item compononent code is :

```
          <li>
          <a href="#">
              <div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">{{ hashtag }}</button>
              </div>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
```

When I look for the HTML generated in dev tools (Chrome), I see

```
ul > app-event-item > li > a > div > button
```

then

```
ul > li > a > div > button
```

for the statics one.

So the only difference is this level `"app-event-item"` that I created with Angular, but I don't understand why it change the way it look.

Comment: Pretty sure, regardless of anything else, links cannot have `button`s as descendants...it's invalid HTML

Comment: Or any block level elements.   You would want the `(click)` function for that.   Outside of that, I am not sure which element you are actually trying to target.   Wouldn't you use a custom class, like `.my-element-style {}` and add it to the element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the button being a descendent of the anchor tag. @jpluton can you include your CSS? I think it's more of an issue of `<li>` not being a direct descendent of `<ul>` but you can work around that by setting styles to `:host` in your component's css file.

Comment: I think it's actually an Angular issue : I've got the same issue on other part of pages : I got a bootstrap static theme (I didn't write the css, just got a theme ready-to-use, and I'm trying to dynamise it with Angular. So when I replace static blocs like the <li> by an angular component, my source has a new tag (the one I created, here <app-event-item>, and I guess the CSS is bothered by this tag. I think I forget a step like "how could I update or reference the bootstrap css I got in the Angular integration"...

Comment: OK writing help me to think...A solution worked, but it's ugly and I think just pointing the problem, I compared each CSS in the chrome toolkit, and found a .dropdown-menu > li > a (inherited from bootstrap) not present for the dynamic version. When I rewrite this in my css component it's Ok (but bad, due to the duplication...)