# Fit 'a' element to button size

Tags: css, html, button, href

Well, I have two buttons (in Spanish) and these buttons are inside an 'a' (link tag) so that:

```
<div class="MB789">
    <a href="#"><button class="B121">Ya soy miembro</button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="B122">Quiero unirme</button></a>
</div>
```

The purpose of the 'a' is obviously to redirect the user to the respective page and the buttons are for the style (yes, I want the user to see buttons and not links)

In the CSS I wrote the following:

```
.MB789{
    display: table;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.MB789 button{
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.MB789 a{
    margin: 10px;
    background: red; /*Debug: to visualize the elements 'a'*/
}
```

This is the result:

[image: button inside a tag]

And that's the problem, that the 'a' elements stand out from the buttons.

And this is what happens when I tell the elements to show themselves as a table.

```
.MB789 a{
    display: table;
    background: red; /*Debug: to visualize the elements 'a'*/
}
```

Then this is what happens:

[image]

What I want is that 'a' elements do not protrude from the buttons, but that when the user click on a button, be redirected to the respective link.

**Note:** I know that Javascript can be redirected, but I refrain from doing this using that language because the user can disable Javascript from the browser settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot nest `<button></button>` elements inside an `<a>` tag, that is invalid markup. Please see why here: [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)

Secondly you can style the `<a>` tag like a button and this will resolve your problem.

Your HTML markup needs to look like this:

```
<div class="MB789">
  <a href="#">Ya soy miembro</a>
  <a href="#">Quiero unirme</a>
</div>
```

Your CSS would look like this:

```
.MB789{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.MB789 a{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The wrapping class should be a `display: block` I think. Otherwise the div might end up flowing with any other inline content around it.

Answer (score 1):

You've put a `10px` margin on the buttons, because they're inside of the `a` tags this margin will be between the buttons and the edge of the `a` tags, making them protrude out from the button. Try removing that margin:

```
.MB789 button{
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: No, because even though I take away the margin, I still have the same problem

Comment: I do not understand, I've tried your code and I still have the same problem

Comment: What browser are you running it on? I'm on Chrome and there's no red visible

Comment: Now I'm testing my site in the Opera browser

Comment: Thanks for your help :)