# React Link tag is preventing flex-boxes from working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to allow a button on my website to provide a link.
So far it can be implemented using the `<link to "...">`  tag.

However I also need my button to stick to the bottom of the column. I have completed this in the code however when I nest my button in the `<Link>` tags, the button is no longer sticking to the bottom. Therefore the `<Link>` tag is stopping the button from working.

```
<div className="col-12 col-lg-6 text-left">
    <div className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <Link to="/portfolio/website-designs#">
            <button type="button" className="btn-outline-primary mt-auto" style={{
                'pointer-events': 'none'
            }}>   <b> Button Text </b>
            </button>
        </Link>
    </div>
```

If I remove the `<Link>` it works.

Is it because the mt-auto is working directly on the parent, the link tag?
I tried nesting the Link inside around the `<b> Button Text </b>`, but the link wasen't working now.

Placing the link button side, unfortunately does not make the link work.

i.e.

```
<button type="button" className="btn-lg btn-outline-primary mt-auto"<Link to"..."> <b> Learn More </b> </Link> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw the Link tag inside of the button tag.  I'd imagine that would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Link is directly under .d-flex so it's stretching 100% as a flexbox element. When you remove Link, Button goes under flexbox and stretch 100%... but if you place button under Link... Link stretch but the button doesn't (as it's not directly under the flexbox). You can add a class  `w-100` into your button to make it stretch

Comment: Also like to mention that Button inside Link isn't necessary, You can add className="btn ... and other class names from button" to the Link element to make it look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass className to the Link component:

```
<Link to="/portfolio/website-designs#" className="btn-outline-primary mt-auto">
  Button Text
</Link>
```

This will allow your `mt-class`, which I'm assuming controls your layout, to behave as you expect it to.

You can read more about `<Link />` here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/others

---

An important side note is that your current markup would result in a button within an anchor tag which isn't valid html and could cause accessibility issues.

This is very well explained in here: [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)