# jquery need to switch text on click and switch back again when clicked second time

Tags: jquery, html

I can get one change, but not the second, not sure if it has to do with document.ready and I need another value?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pause").click(function() {
    $("#stopme").attr('value', 'Resume');
    document.getElementById('stopme').id = 'resumeme';
    document.getElementById('pause').id = 'resume';
  });

});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#resume").click(function() {
    $("#resumeme").attr('value', 'Pause Boxes');
    document.getElementById('resumeme').id = 'stopme';
    document.getElementById('resume').id = 'pause';
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="pause"> <input type="button" value="Pause Boxes" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="stopme"> </a>
```

Comment: You shouldn't put a button inside an anchor, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: Don't change the IDs, just have the handler check the value and do whatever is appropriate.