# How am I able to change multiple blocks in a div on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm creating a navigation bar with multiple buttons. The buttons have a text-shadow to stand out on a background image I have on my page, as the navigation bar is transparent. As I hover over the nav, the nav takes on a background color, and I'd like all of the buttons to remove its text-shadow as it's not eye appealing. As I hover on a button, that button is the only one without the text-shadow, while the other buttons still have it. Any solutions? I'm pretty sure this should be simple.

```css
nav button {
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-size: 170%;
  color: hsla(48, 70%, 63%, 1);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0% 2% 0% 2%;
  /* To give space    between    the buttons */
  padding: .3% 2% .6% 2%;
  /* To give space    inside    the buttons */
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav button:hover {
  background-color: hsla(9, 57%, 50%, 1);
  color: hsla(48, 70%, 83%, 1);
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <hr>
  <a href="Big Duck.html"><button>Home</button></a>
  <a href="Menu.html"><button>Menu</button></a>
  <a href="Photogallery.html"><button>Photogallery</button></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: you cannot put a button inside an anchor tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: I made you a snippet. It seems the snippet does what you describe. Can you elaborate on expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remove the buttons inside the `a` tag since you can't have buttons inside them. Then what you want to do is something like this:

```css
nav a {
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-size: 170%;
  color: hsla(48, 70%, 63%, 1);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0% 2% 0% 2%;
  /* To give space    between    the buttons */
  padding: .3% 2% .6% 2%;
  /* To give space    inside    the buttons */
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav:hover{ 
  background-color: hsla(9, 57%, 50%, 1);
}
nav:hover a{ 
  text-shadow:none;
  background-color: hsla(9, 57%, 50%, 1);
  color: hsla(48, 70%, 83%, 1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <hr>
  <a href="Big Duck.html">Home</a>
  <a href="Menu.html">Menu</a>
  <a href="Photogallery.html">Photogallery</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I would expect text-decoration: none; somewhere, but it does not work on hover

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for this set:

```css
nav button {
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-size: 170%;
  color: hsla(48, 70%, 63%, 1);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0% 2% 0% 2%;
  /* To give space    between    the buttons */
  padding: .3% 2% .6% 2%;
  /* To give space    inside    the buttons */
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav:hover {
  background-color: hsla(9, 57%, 50%, 1);
}

nav:hover button {
  background-color: hsla(9, 57%, 50%, 1);
  color: hsla(48, 70%, 83%, 1);
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <hr>
  <a href="Big Duck.html"><button>Home</button></a>
  <a href="Menu.html"><button>Menu</button></a>
  <a href="Photogallery.html"><button>Photogallery</button></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have tried.

I have eliminated **button** tag inside **a** tag to follow best practice.

```css
nav a {
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-size: 170%;
  color: hsla(48, 70%, 63%, 1);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0% 2% 0% 2%;
  /* To give space    between    the buttons */
  padding: .3% 2% .6% 2%;
  /* To give space    inside    the buttons */
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: hsla(9, 57%, 50%, 1);
  color: hsla(48, 70%, 83%, 1);
  text-shadow: none;
}

nav:hover a {
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="Big Duck.html">Home</a>
  <a href="Menu.html">Menu</a>
  <a href="Photogallery.html">Photogallery</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey @furydart, can you provide an explanation of what you did? It looks like what you have it right but having an explanation to go with the solution helps others learn rather than just copying and pasting code.

Comment: I have added following style to hide text shadow of entire nav bar.
**nav:hover a {text-shadow: none;}**