# why is my GetMapping Annotation not being recognized

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request-mapping, get-mapping

So here is my Controller. First of all, here I have both request methods GET and POST but for some strange reason the `GetMapping("/journeys")` is not being recognized.

```
   @Controller
   @GetMapping("/journeys")
     String journeys(Model model , @Valid JourneyForm form) {
        model.addAttribute("journeys", journeys.findAll()) ; 
        model.addAttribute("form", form);
        return "journeys" ;} 
   @GetMapping("/jounreyCreate")
   String createJourney(Model model , JourneyForm form){
       model.addAttribute("form", form) ;

       return "journeyCreate" ;
   }
   @PostMapping("/journeyCreate")
   String createJourney(Model model ,Errors errors,@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") JourneyForm form ) { 
       if (errors.hasErrors()) {
           return journeys(model , form);
       }
       journeys.save( form.createJourney() ) ;  
       return "redirect:/journeys";
   }
```

and here is the JourneyForm Class

```
 public class JourneyForm {

 private String name;

 public JourneyForm(String name) {
     this.name = name ; 

 }

 public String getName() {
         return name;
     }

 public Journey createJourney() {    
     return new Journey(getName());
 }
 }
```

and for the last part the `journey.html` and journeyCreate.html

```
<body>
 <h2 th:text="#{journeys.title}">Reise</h2>

    <a href="/journeyCreate">
        <button class="ui button">Journey erstellen</button>
    </a>
    <a href="/journeyEdit">
        <button class="ui button">Reise bearbeiten</button>
    </a>

    <div th:each="journey : ${journeys}">
        <p th:text="'Reise: '+${journey.name}">Reise</p>


    </div>
```

and `journeyCreate.html`

```
   <a href="/journeys">
        <button class="ui button">Zurück zur Reise</button>
    </a>

     <form  role="form" class="ui form" id="form" th:object="${form}" th:method="post" th:action="@{/journeyCreate}">

        <div class="field">
            <label for="journeyName">Name</label>
            <input id="journeyName" name="journeyName" type="text" th:field="*{name}" th:errorclass="is-invalid" required="required"/><br/>
            <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a name.</div> 
        </div>  
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

it is really frustrating and I can't get my hand on the cause

Your help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the URL directly? I suspect that it's working just fine and that `<a><button/></a>` is not legal HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: Is it a typo or is your `journeys`method annotated separately as a Controller?
(and I agree with @drekbour)