# Is background-color:inherit expected to work in IE11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The CSS 'background-color:inherit;' doesn't seem to work with IE11.

Given this HTML:

```
<a style="background-color:#002538;">
  <button type="button" style="background-color:inherit;" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me! 
  </button>
</a>
```

In Chrome you end up with this:
[image: chrome-button]

But in IE11 you end up with this:
[image]

Other CSS properties like 'padding' seem to work fine with inheritance. Is this expected behavior?

[Example to try in both Chrome and IE11 to see the difference](https://liveweave.com/wZHwAD)

IE version 11.418.18362.0

Comment: Nesting a button (`<button>`) in a link/anchor (`<a>`) is invalid HTML. If you use valid HTML, it’ll probably work more consistently. (And it’ll actually make sense.)

Comment: @Ry- It's actually not that simple unfortunately, IE just has trouble with this particular property on input elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `inherit` is generally support in IE11, it is not supported on backgrounds for various input elements.

If you just want the background to match that of the parent element, using `transparent` instead could be a good way to fake it in most cases. Also you shouldn't wrap the `button` in an `a` tag since that's not valid even in HTML5, though this is not the cause of your troubles.

```html
<span style="background-color:#002538;">
  <button type="button" style="background-color:transparent;" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me! 
  </button>
</span>
```

Otherwise you will have to specify the color on the element itself.

Comment: In case you're like me and didn't realize that having a <button> within an <a> is frowned on, see this helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: Also, contrary to popular belief, background-color:transparent; is not supported by IE11 by default, at least not for <button> elements: it needs to be explicitly set.

(The 'popular belief': https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-color.asp)