# How to make a button link open in a new tab only using HTML?

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, attributes

I have this piece of code:

```
<button name='link' onclick="window.location.href = 'Text.html';"  
style="cursor:pointer"  class='Text' value='Text.html' title='Text'>Text</button>
```

On click it will take you to one of my sub-sites. I wanted it to open the link in a new tab so I tried putting `target='_blank'` in the button tag, but it didn`t work. If possible I would prefer to use HTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** While the original answer works, it isn't in line with the W3C HTML5 specs. An alternative would be to edit the JavaScript in the `onclick` attribute to open the link in a new tab.

```html
<button
  onclick="window.open('Text.html', '_blank')"
  name="link"
  style="cursor: pointer"
  class="Text"
  value="Text.html"
  title="Text"
>
  Text
</button>
```

---

You could wrap an `<a>` tag around the button instead.

```html
<a href="Text.html" target="_blank">
  <button
    name="link"
    style="cursor: pointer"
    class="Text"
    value="Text.html"
    title="Text"
  >
    Text
  </button>
</a>
```

Comment: you really shouldn't put button tags in a tag

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: True, would not be best practice. You can edit your `onclick` attribute to `window.open('Text.html', '_blank')` if you don't mind throwing in some JS.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `form`

```
<form action="//example.com/Text.html" target="_blank">
    <button type="submit">Text</button>
</form>
```

This can take to different site or any of your sub-site.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace button tag with a**

```
<a href="Text.html" title="Text" target="_blank">Text</a>
```