# The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element how to solve it

Tags: html, css, button

I try to validate my code but the "The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element" keeps showing and I have seriously no idea how to solve it, here is an example of how it looks. Thank you

```html
<a href=#boats><button><img src="img/boats.png" alt="Boating"></button></a>
```

Comment: Anchors can't contain buttons in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

Certain elements aren't allowed inside `<a>` tags.

Check this SO post for a list of which ones: [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one of the `button` and `a` tags. You can create the same effect of the `href` in a button using some of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link).