# how to clear black dash in html button?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to describe my problem but look at my output you'll get an idea. I
googled about my problem but i couldn't found the solution.
[image: Output Image]

```css
.btn1 {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #f7e7e7;
  color: rgb(49, 126, 126);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(186, 230, 173);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(98, 151, 98);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn1">Home</button>
  </a>
  <a href="product.html">
    <button class="btn2">Products</button>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn3">Buy Now</button>
  </a>
  <a href="findus.html">
    <button class="btn4">Find us</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Every button have same code in CSS.
Can you please tell, what am i doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: You have wrapped the buttons using anchor tag. Anchor tag add underline to the text by default. In your case Anchor tag is treating buttons as a text and adding underline. So if you want to remove underline, you have to add property TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;.

Comment: Got it.@AjayMalhotra thank you

Comment: Links cannot contain buttons and vice versa6. It's invalid HTML

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have unnecessarily wrapped each of your `<button>`s in an `<a>` tag and this is the browser's default underline style of the `<a>` tag that you can see.

Note: Some of the other answers suggest simply hiding the underline, but wrapping a `<button>` in an `<a>` [is considered to be an anti-pattern that should be avoided.](https://www.htmhell.dev/4-link-also-button/)

### Links

```css
.btn1 {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #f7e7e7;
  color: rgb(49, 126, 126);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(186, 230, 173);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(98, 151, 98);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="btn1" href="#">Home</a>
  <a class="btn1" href="product.html">Products</a>
  <a class="btn1" href="#">Buy Now</a>
  <a class="btn1" href="findus.html">Find us</a>
</div>
```

### Buttons

```css
.btn1 {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #f7e7e7;
  color: rgb(49, 126, 126);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(186, 230, 173);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(98, 151, 98);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn1">Home</button>
  <button class="btn2">Products</button>
  <button class="btn3">Buy Now</button>
  <button class="btn4">Find us</button>
</div>
```

You can read about [links vs buttons](https://marcysutton.com/links-vs-buttons-in-modern-web-applications), and why you might choose one over the other here.

Answer (score 5):

The dashes you are seeing are actually the default underline that accompanies anchor elements. All you need to add is:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

That being said, nesting button elements inside of anchor elements [is invalid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/8360496) and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `a` with button or use css rule `text-decoration: none`

Answer (score -2):

```css
.btn {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  margin: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #f7e7e7;
  color: rgb(49, 126, 126);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(186, 230, 173);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(98, 151, 98);
}

a
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    Home
  </a>
  <a href="product.html" class="btn">
   Product
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">
   buy now
  </a>
  <a href="findus.html" class="btn">
    find us
  </a>
</div>
```