# How to enclose a button in RouterLink, so that the navigation does not occur on button click

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

Let's say, I have the following markup:

```html
<RouterLink tag="div" to="/somepath">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    ...
    <button>A button</button>
</RouterLink>
```

I'm using `tag="div"`, because nesting a `<button>` inside an `a` element [is not valid HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6393827/11105280).

With this markup, clicking anywhere inside the `RouterLink`, including a paragraph and a button, will cause navigation.

But my requirement is that clicking on the button does not cause navigation, but clicking on other elements does.

So, I use a `div` with `@click` handler that checks whether the clicked element is a button or its descendant and only navigates if not:

```html
<div @click="navigateSomewhere">
    ...
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    navigateSomewhere($event) {
      if(!$event.closest("button"))
        this.$router.push("/somePath")
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this.

I have also created an MCVE: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routerlink-button-3dlyx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<button @click.prevent="">A button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's becouse the button is under "the clicking area" that menas that is not targettable, try to set the position relative and the z-index: 99 to the button, and let me know

Comment: I have tried your solution, and unfortunately, it is not working

Comment: Can u post your "builded" version of this code? so i can try, becouse i think is css related

Comment: Sure, I'm in the progress of creating an MCVE

Comment: Just edited the question to include information about the MCVE