# HTML - Dropdown with ahref and button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I am creating a dropdown list with text and a delete button, but I have a small issue. When pressing the `ahref` link, it redirects perfectly to the website, but when pressing the delete button, it displays the popup message as it should, but then redirect to the `ahref` link. I don't want it to redirect when pressing the delete button. How can I avoid this?

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("You clicked the button");
  return;
}
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
 
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

#main-container {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#navbar {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#navbar a.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.home {
    background-color: green;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
 /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.deleteBtn {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-container">

  <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <a href="home.php" class="home">Home</a>
        
        <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <!-- Dropdown value below, value is for testing purpose -->
      <a href="https://google.com/">Google
      <button type='deleteBtn' onclick="myFunction()">X</button>
      </a>
      <a href="https://youtube.com/">Youtube
      <button type='deleteBtn' onclick="myFunction()">X</button>
      </a>
      <a href="https://amazon.com/">Amazon
      <button type='deleteBtn' onclick="myFunction()">X</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
    
<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not nest action elements. Buttons should never end up inside an A tag. And vice versa. Use a parent for both the A and Button instead. On button X click remove that parent that contains them both.

Comment: try thsi    function myFunction() {
  alert("You clicked the button");
  return false;
}

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Oh, I didn't know. Could you please provide an example for me?

Comment: @Azhar That still makes it redirect after the alert.

Comment: <a href="https://amazon.com/">Amazon
     
      </a>
 <button type='deleteBtn' onclick="myFunction()">X</button>

Comment: remove button from <a href></a>

Comment: `type='deleteBtn'` is an invalid attribute!

Comment: use this one  <button type='button' onclick="myFunction()">X</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `#navbar` should not be inside `#main-container`!
- Don't place `<button>` inside `<a>` and vice-versa.
- Use a common parent for both your `<a>` and `<button>` instead. (I.e: use an `<ul>` and `<li>` list)
- `type='deleteBtn'` is an invalid attribute. Use class instead `class='deleteBtn'`
- Don't use inline `on*` handlers. JS should be in one place only, and that's your `script`

**Edited CSS and HTML:**

```js
function removeListItem(ev) {
  const EL_list = ev.currentTarget.closest("li")
  EL_list.remove();
}

const ELS_deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteBtn");
ELS_deleteBtn.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", removeListItem));
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; }

html {height: 100%;}
body {height: 100%; font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#navbar>a {
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar .home {
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-list li {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-list li a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  flex: 1;
}

.dropdown-list li:hover a {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#main-container {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
  <a href="home.php" class="home">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <ul class="dropdown-list">
        <li>
          <a href="https://google.com/">Google</a>
          <button class='deleteBtn'>X</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://youtube.com/">Youtube</a>
          <button class='deleteBtn'>X</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://amazon.com/">Amazon</a>
          <button class='deleteBtn'>X</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main-container">
  <h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
  <p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But for further experience - why `Don't place <button> inside <a> and vice-versa.`?

Comment: @Carmen1 (you're welcome!) For the same reason you don't place an action `<a>` element inside another action `<a>` element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Answer (score -2):

use `preventDefault()`.

[Read More about preventDefault](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("You clicked the button");
  return;
}
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
 
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

#main-container {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#navbar {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#navbar a.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.home {
    background-color: green;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
 /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.deleteBtn {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-container">

  <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <a href="home.php" class="home">Home</a>
        
        <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <!-- Dropdown value below, value is for testing purpose -->
      <a href="https://google.com/">Google
      <button type='deleteBtn' onclick="myFunction(event)">X</button>
      </a>
      <a href="https://youtube.com/">Youtube
      <button type='deleteBtn' onclick="myFunction(event)">X</button>
      </a>
      <a href="https://amazon.com/">Amazon
      <button type='deleteBtn' onclick="myFunction(event)">X</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
    
<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```