# What is the disadvantage of nesting a <button> element inside an <a href>?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to use my custom component (witch I shouldn't modify) to give the desired appearence to my `router-link`. It was the best way I found without need to modify my custom button and still preserve accessibility. As following another topics I've seem, it is semanticly incorrect, but what would be the disadvantage of this approach?

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'my-route-name'}">
  <my-custom-button>
    Go!
  </my-custom-button>
</router-link>
```

Comment: 1. Screen readers may have trouble undertstanding it. 2. no guarantee how it will look cross browser

Comment: Basically, no disadvantage, you will require to style two elements, and handling the default behaviours of the same.

Comment: html5 not valid

Comment: Accessibility would suffer.  You now have 2 clickable things that are nested and it will confuse the user as to which one is triggering which action.  If you want a specific appearance, post your CSS as well and maybe we can give you the desired appearance without hurting accessibility.  Don't just use anchors or buttons for their presentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)

Comment: Thanks, @GrafiCode, but with that question, I still got curious about the disadvantages. Actually, I don't even get that such HTML5 validation error.

Comment: You can always style an `a` tag like a button (i.e. have a class `button` and style that regardless of the HTML element). Why go through the trouble of testing this?

Comment: Thanks, guys, the goal was to avoid using CSS and classes to customize and try to use ready-made components of the in-house Design System, which is undergoing a lot of changes.