# Redirecting with a button

Tags: html

How do I redirect a user to a page if they click a button? This is for a login page. I have tried `href` but it doesn't work. I don't know .php so I am using js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: If this is for a login page, why you don't just submit your form? <button type="submit">

Comment: Thanks, This is pretty useful!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">redirect</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTML button that
        acts like a link

```
<a href='https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/'>
    <button>
        Click Here
    </button>
</a>
```

Comment: it isn't valid HTML5 according to the HTML5 Spec Document from W3C. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: Sorry, I don't use href.