# How to disable an <a> tag in React after clicking it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

How can I disable the below anchor tag in React after it has been clicked? Like the onClick functionality is not working on the anchor tag.

```
<td align="left">
  <input
    type="file"
    accept=".csv,.xlsx,.xls"
    name="image"
    className="file-upload-input"
    onChange={(e: any) => {
      handleFileChange(e, data.c_id);
    }}
  />

  <a
    href="javascript:;"
    className="btn btn-secondary"
    style={{
      width: "125.62px",
      backgroundColor: "#0b5ed7",
      borderColor: "#0a58ca"
    }}
  >
    <img src={UploadIcon.default} />
    Upload
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: try to put a button within <a/> tag ,that way you can conditionally disable it.

Comment: or you can just use a button alternatively:                                                     
```<Button href='/yourRoute' disabled={yourCondition}>Upload</Button>```

Comment: Hey ertemishakk, Thank u so much for your reply. I have used the First one you suggested to me, Giving the button inside the anchor tag.

Comment: Please accept the answer as correct - if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: "*the onClick functionality is not working on the anchor tag*" - I don't see an `onClick` handler on your anchor element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting a conditional class on the anchor tag and disabling it through css? It would need a state variable to hold the disabled state. Code would look something like.

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState();

<a
  href="javascript:;"
  onClick={() => {
  // setting the state on click
    setDisabled(true);
  }}
  // Adding class here
  className={`btn btn-secondary${disabled ? " disabled" : ""}`}
  style={{
    width: "125.62px",
    backgroundColor: "#0b5ed7",
    borderColor: "#0a58ca"
  }}
>
  <img src={""} />
  Upload
</a>
```

And the disabled class

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to put a button within  tag ,that way you can conditionally disable it.

Comment: You shouldn't be nesting `<button>` inside `<a>` elements: that's invalid HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: You might mean around the anchor tag (not within). That's an option