# How do Ilink to a pdf file in html?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, vite

I am building a javascript app using vite js and I am having a problem linking an html file when I finally build and deploy the app to firebase. When I am in dev mode the code opens a new window and displays the pdf file normally ,however it wont show up when i finally build it...

`<div id="link1"> <button id="button"><a class="pdf" href="assets/Hindes_Resume.pdf"  target = "blank">Resume</a></button> </div>`

Comment: Update you html with below html...
`<div id="link1"><a class="pdf" href="assets/Hindes_Resume.pdf"  target="_blank">Resume</a></div>`

Comment: I did that, however it is still just reloading my webpage in another tab. I have feeling it has nothing to do with the html and more to do with the build itself? This is a vite project deployed to firebase hosting

Comment: `<button>` elements cannot include `<a>` elements (nor vice versa). If you are linking somewhere, get rid of the `<button>`.

Comment: "I did that, however it is still just reloading my webpage in another tab. " - Then the URL is wrong. We don't know enough about your build system / deployment process  / server configuration to determine exactly how.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your issue is the **path** given to the `href` attribute of the anchor.  You should use **root absolute path**.

As we do not have more details, I am assuming you have the `assets` directory in the `public` folder - something similiar to the following tree:

```
| public
|-- assets
|---- Hindes_Resume.pdf
| src
| package.json
...
```

Using **absolute path** : `href="/assets/Hindes_Resume.pdf"`

```html
<div id="link1"> <button id="button"><a class="pdf" href="/assets/Hindes_Resume.pdf"  target = "blank">Resume</a></button> </div>
```

You can learn more about **vite's static assets handling** by reading the [offical documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html).

**OT Note:**

- Also, as Quentin stated, you should not nest an `a` element into a `button` element, I suggest you to give a read to this answer: [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)