# Html Button wrapped with anchor tags redirecting to ancor tag URL instead of button Onlick property

Tags: html, django

I have an HTML code in my Django project. I used an anchor tag to wrap a button. The anchor tag has its own `href` and the button also has an `onclick` property that when pressed will lead to a different destination. see code below

```
<article class="card-group-item">
                    <header class="card-header"><h4 class="title">Links </h4></header>
                    <div class="filter-content">
                        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <a href={{ add_drug_disposal_url }} class="list-group-item">Drug
                                Disposal form
                                <button class="button"
                                        onclick={{ add_drug_disposal_upload_url }}>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                            <a href={{ add_chain_of_custody_url }} class="list-group-item">Chain
                                of custody
                                <button class="button"
                                        onclick={{ add_chain_of_custody_upload_url }}>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                            <a href={{ add_drug_disposal_url }} class="list-group-item">Incident
                                and Temperature Excursion Report
                                <button class="button"
                                        onclick={{ add_incident_report_upload_url }}>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </div>  <!-- list-group .// -->
                    </div>
                </article> <!-- card-group-item.// -->
```

how can I make sure that the button `onclick` will trigger when the button is pressed and not that of the anchor tag?

note that all URLs are being picked by the template from the view just fine

Comment: I'm not sure of the logic of why you're wrapping the button within the link instead of just keeping it separate, however, this is not valid HTML.  You can *stye* a button to look like a link, but you can not nest a button within an anchor tag.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/10951070

Comment: raphael is correct.  My first thought is that it seems you want two view functions to be called when you click the button, is that right?  I'd consider rolling that functionality into a single view, or updating your backend logic in some other way to handle both operations.  Hard to say what you should do since we can't see what `add_drug_disposal_upload_url` or `add_drug_disposal_url` are doing.