# How to make a specific child of a parent that is clickable to not get the property

Tags: reactjs

So, what I want to achieve is that the wrapping link I have to be clickable on all places, instead when the button is clicked don't call the function or click the item

```
<a href="test.com">
 <img />
 <title />
 <button>
  Add to Cart
 </button>
</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, mixing a link and a button isn't a good idea [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)

Second of all use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75838680/react-parent-clickable-box-has-child-clickable-button