# React Parent Clickable Box has Child Clickable Button

Tags: reactjs

We have Banner Ad in React where whole green box is clickable (goes to a product page).
In upper right, child component of the box, is a clickable exit ad (closes the ad).

How does React prioritize parent level buttons, with child level button?

In Chrome, we have a bug, some environments havethe exit close the ad, while others are complaining the exit has same behavior as parent (goes to to product page).

What is the ideal way to code for this, to prevent bugs, since my code has issues below?

[image]

```
<UpsellStyledCard onClick={handleClickProductPage}
    <UpsellTitle>
        Ad Test
    </UpsellTitle>
    <UpsellCloseButton
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClose}
     >
     </UpsellCloseButton>
    </UpsellStyledTitle>
</UpsellStyledCard>
```

We are using Typescript function components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking the "close" button, use `event.stopPropagation` to prevent events from bubbling up

```
<UpsellCloseButton
  type="button"
  onClick={(e) => { 
    e.stopPropagation();
    handleClose();
  }}
>
</UpsellCloseButton>
```