# Why my hyperlink doesn't work as it should be?

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink

I've started learning HTML recently, and I've understood a lot of things so far. The last thing I've learned was about forms. For practising, I've decided that I would like to make a website, which contains a bit of everything.
The problem occures here:

```
<input  type="e-mail" name="email" value="" placeholder="xxx@yyy.com">
```

```
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</a>
```

Now what I would like to do, as you've already figured, is that if I fill my e-mail address, I would be redirected to the Thank_You.html file.

I've created the file for it already, and it looks like this, and works perfectly fine aswell:

```
    <a href="../HTML_102/forms.html">

        <button type="submit">Go back</button>


    </a>


</div>
```

But the problem is, that it doesn't work in the forms.html file, for some reason. It behaves like that it would be a type="reset" button, whereas it should be a type="submit".

I'll also share my codepen links here, so you can take a look.

forms.html
https://codepen.io/ngabor9601/pen/ZExaBgV

Thank_You.html
https://codepen.io/ngabor9601/pen/YzaEpmW

Thanks in advance!
G

Comment: Remove the `<a>` around your submit button, and take that `href` and put it inside of the `<form action='URLHERE'>`

Comment: Your [mcve] needs to be here, not on codepen

Comment: Sorry everyone, for some reason, I can not copy the problematic part here. I do not really understand the reason, why it does not become visible.

<div>

    <input  type="e-mail" name="email" value="" placeholder="xxx@yyy.com">
<div>
    <a href="../HTML_102/Thank_You.html">

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </a>

</div>


   

</div>

Comment: a submit button inside of a link. That is some invalid HTML.

Comment: @epascarello Is it? Why is that so? It works now tough.

Comment: Well you are having issues.... ;)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: If you are trying to submit a form and redirect, you need to rethink your whole operation. You can not do two navigation tasks at the same time in the same browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Okay! So meanwhile I've found the solution, altough I do not really understand why this solved the problem:

```
<div>
    <input required type="email" 
    name="email" 
    value="example@example.com" 
    placeholder="Enter your e-mail address">
    </div>
```

```
<a href="../HTML_102/Thank_You.html">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</a>
```

So now it works perfectly, but can someone please explain, why did it work only if I input the link outside of the form element?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it like so

```
<form>
  <input type="button" 
    onclick="window.location.href='../HTML_102/forms.html';" value="Back" />
</form>
```