# I had a clickable svg that dispatched a stimulus action. I'm trying to recreate the same behaviour using turbo and it's not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been working on a demo app in Rails 7.

In one of my views I had the html element `'example-element'` which was an image. Clicking the image engaged the `link_to` tag and directed the user to the `example_path`. A second element, the svg `'overlay-element'` was superimposed over the image. Clicking the svg specifically would dispatch the `@example.id` to the Stimulus controller `overlay#exampleAction`. Clicking anywhere else on the image would engage the `link_to` tag.

```
<%= link_to example_path(@example), id: 'example-element' do %>
    <%= image_tag @example.image %>
    <svg 
        id="overlay-element"
        data-controller="overlay"
        data-action="click->overlay#exampleAction"
        data-example-id="<%= @example.id %>"
        fill="red" 
        viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
        stroke-width="1.5" 
        stroke="currentColor" 
    >
        <path 
            d="M11..." 
        />
    </svg>
<% end %>
```

I have updated the code to achieve the same goal with `Turbo`. I extracted the svg element out into a partial and wrapped it in a `turbo_frame_tag` and created a new rails controller `overlay` to receive the post action.

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'layouts/overlay_element' do %>
    <%= button_to overlay_path(example_id: example.id), method: :post do %>
        <svg 
            id="overlay-element"
            fill="red" 
            viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
            stroke-width="1.5" 
            stroke="currentColor" 
        >
            <path 
                d="M11..." 
            />
        </svg>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I updated the `'example-element'` to render the `overlay_element` partial where I previously had the Stimulus/svg code and pass the `@example` object in to it.

```
<%= link_to example_path(@example), id: 'example-element' do %>
    <%= image_tag @example.image %>
    <%= render 'layouts/overlay_element', example: @example %>
<% end %>
```

It works...sort of...
If I remove the `link_to` tag from the `'example-element'` then clicking on the `'overlay-element'` posts to the `overlay` rails controller as expected. If I reinstate the `link_to` tag to the `'example-element'` then clicking anywhere on the `'example-element'` OR the `'overlay-element'` engages the `link_to` tag of the `'example-element'`. Effectively the `'overlay-element'` is now not clickable if the `'example-element'` has the `link_to` tag.

I hoped initially that it might be a `z-index` issue so I adjusted it to make sure the `'overlay-element'` was above the `'example-element'` but that didn't work.

Is the problem that I now have a `button` effectively nested inside a link where before I had a clickable html element nested inside a link? Is it a problem that one is using `Turbo` and the other is not?

Is there a way of fixing this so that I can click on the `'overlay-element'` separately from the `'example-element'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a wrapper div to keep the link and button separate and use absolute positioning in CSS to overlap the two? Having a `button` nested within an `a` element is invalid in HTML5 ([Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)).

Something like:

```
<div id="example-element">
  <%= link_to example_path(@example) do %>
    <%= image_tag @example.image %>
  <% end %>
  <%= turbo_frame_tag 'layouts/overlay_element' %>
</div>
```