# What can I do to improve my code and how to solve this error? Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: next.js

I created a React and Next.js website, and I'm refactoring my code to clean console erros. The website has multiple languages and dark/light theme.

When I run `npm run dev`, it shows this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <main> in <div>.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Component Stack
main
Home
ThemeProvider
MyApp
```

I think there is something wrong in my HTML, but I can't find out what is wrong.

Here is my `index.tsx`

```
import Metatags from "@/components/Metatags";
import { useTheme } from "../context/ThemeContext";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Popup from "@/components/Popup";
import { useState } from 'react';

export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }: { locale: string }) => {
    return {
        props: {
            ...await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common']),
        },
    }
}

function Home() {
    const { theme } = useTheme();
    const { t, i18n, ready } = useTranslation('common');
    const bgOpacity = 'bg-opacity-75';
    const textColor = theme === 'light' ? 'text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-100';
    const isDark = theme === 'dark';
    const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(true);
    let logoSrc = theme === "dark" ? "/images/logo-dark.png" : "/images/logo-light.png";
    let presentationSrc = theme === "dark" ? "/images/presentation-dark.png" : "/images/presentation-light.png";
    let dateSrc = theme === "dark" ? "/images/date-dark.png" : "/images/date-light.png";
    let openBarBannerSrc = theme === "dark" ? "/images/open-bar-banner-dark.png" : "/images/open-bar-banner-light.png";

    useEffect(() => {
        if (i18n.isInitialized) {
            i18n.changeLanguage(i18n.language);
        }
    }, [i18n]);

    if (!ready) {
        return (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        );
    }
    return (
        <main>
            <Metatags title="Title | Title" description="Description" />
            <Popup show={showPopup} onClose={() => setShowPopup(false)} />
            <div className="relative flex h-screen content-center items-center justify-center pt-16 pb-32">
                <div className={`absolute top-0 h-full w-full ${bgOpacity} bg-cover bg-center`} />
                <div className="max-w-8xl container relative mx-auto">
                    <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center">
                        <div className={`ml-auto mr-auto w-full px-4 text-center lg:w-8/12  ${textColor}`}>
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-full w-full pb-5">
                                <Image src={presentationSrc} alt="Welcome" width={142} height={56} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-full w-full">
                                <Image src={logoSrc} alt="Welcome" width={800} height={300} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-full w-full pt-5">
                                <Image src={dateSrc} alt="Welcome" width={174} height={45} />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-full w-full">
                                    <Image src={openBarBannerSrc} alt="Welcome" width={297} height={38} />
                                </div>
                                <Link href="/tickets">
                                    <button
                                        className={`uppercase border-2 py-2 px-4 mt-2 rounded ${isDark ? 'bg-gray-900 border-yellow-400 text-yellow-400 hover:bg-yellow-400 hover:text-black' : 'border-yellow-900 text-yellow-900 hover:bg-yellow-900 hover:text-yellow-400'}`}
                                    >
                                        {t('ticketsButton')}
                                    </button>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

I know my code is bad, so, any suggestion of what to improve is welcome.

EDIT: I tried to simplify the index.tsx commenting line by line and then uncomment, and I noted that is when I uncomment these lines that the errors started to appear:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ locale }: { locale: string }) {
    return {
        props: {
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common'])),
        },
    };
}
```

I think the problem is how I'm configuring something, I really don't know.

`next-i18next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'pt-BR',
        locales: ['en-US', 'es-ES', 'pt-BR'],
    },
};
```

`next.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');
const nextConfig = {
    i18n
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

_app.tsx:

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar';
import WhatsAppButton from '@/components/WhatsAppButton';
import { ThemeProvider } from '../context/ThemeContext';
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Metatags from '@/components/Metatags';
import nextI18NextConfig from '../next-i18next.config.js';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const routes = [
        { name: 'Path', path: '/' },
//other paths
    ];

    return (
        <ThemeProvider>
            <Metatags />
            <Navbar routes={routes} />
            <Component {...pageProps} key={router.locale} />
            <WhatsAppButton />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp, nextI18NextConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong import. I solved my problem just changing it:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
```

to:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hydration Error Fix**

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <main> in <div>.
```

The hydration error is happening because when the server prerenders your code, `ready` is likely undefined or some nullish value, so your component returns a `<div>` element. Then when the client is hydrated with JavaScript, `ready` changes to `true` and returns the `<main>` element. NextJS gives some possible solutions to hydration errors, and the one they suggest that I think would work best in your case is [this one](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error#solution-1-using-useeffect-to-run-on-the-client-only):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true)
  }, [])

  return <h1>{isClient ? 'This is never prerendered' : 'Prerendered'}</h1>
}
```

In your case, you can add the above code and add a check to your if statement to show the Loading div if it's not ready and it's not client:

```
if (!ready && !isClient) {
    return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
    );
}
```

**General Improvements**

1. `isDark`: I noticed that you are checking for the dark theme with `theme === "dark"` in several places. You already have a variable created called `isDark` that does this check for you, so I would update all other instances of `theme === "dark"` with your `isDark` variable.
2. `<Image />` alt text: It looks like each `<Image />` has the same "Welcome" alt text. If this is intended, you can ignore this bit of feedback. Otherwise, it's best to make sure you have a descriptive alt text for what the image represents. When I'm coming up with alt text, I like to think, "Can I imagine what the image might be based on the alt text?". [Google gives some good advice when it comes to alt text](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/google-images#descriptive-alt-text%20descriptive-titles-captions-filenames).
3. Nested `<button>` within `<Link>`: NextJS's `<Link />` component resolves to an anchor tag, and buttons should never be nested within an anchor tag. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/20913924) goes into more detail on why this is the case, and in your case, I would move the className on your button to the Link component like so:

```
<Link
   href="/tickets"
   className={`uppercase border-2 py-2 px-4 mt-2 rounded ${isDark ? 'bg-gray-900 border-yellow-400 text-yellow-400 hover:bg-yellow-400 hover:text-black' : 'border-yellow-900 text-yellow-900 hover:bg-yellow-900 hover:text-yellow-400'}`}
>
     {t('ticketsButton')}
</Link>
```

Comment: I tried to simplify my index.tsx file and I noted that when I remove "export async function getServerSideProps" (...) all the erros go away. I edited my question.