# Styling the browse button to look like a link

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a <button> that's a link in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341011/making-a-button-thats-a-link-in-html)
>   [How apply CSS to browse button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365431/how-apply-css-to-browse-button)

How to style the browse button to look like a link?

I mean the

```
<input type=file />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

1. Overlay a div on top of input file.
2. Change the opacity of input file to 0.

   ```
   div.text {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       text-decoration: underline;
       color: blue;
   }
   div.wrapper {
       position: relative;
   }
   input { opacity: 0; }
   ​

   <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="text">I'm not a link you fool</div>
       <input type="file"/>
   </div>
   ​
   ```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/BZeMG/

Answer (score 1):

this tutorial should be help u,

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the browse button of a `<input type=file />` you can't do that. You have to go for a jquery/ajax file upload plugin, that replaces the original button with something custom. Take a look at the list here:

http://creativefan.com/10-ajax-jquery-file-uploaders/

and see if you find something you like.