# Remove dash between two button links

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

I have created a page with two buttons (that are links) on a page. For an uknown reason, a dash displays between the buttons in chrome, ff, and ie. I am trying to get just a little bit of space between the buttons instead of this weird dash. Here is some simple sample code to replicate the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='utf-8'> 

<html>
    <head><title>Button Dashes?</title></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
                <button>Google</button>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">
                <button>Yahoo</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do to remove the dash between the buttons?

Comment: That's called whitespace, why do you have buttons in links anyway?

Comment: The dash is a white-space character after the button which is underlined because it is in an anchor. Remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: Whitespace is space that is white. This is a distinct dash. I have the page structured the way it is from following this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341011/making-a-button-thats-a-link-in-html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your code to this:

```
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.google.com"><button>Google</button></a>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><button>Yahoo</button></a>
    </div>
```

Default style for links have `underlines` so the whitespace is going to be just an underline. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wCfBR/

Here are some alternative ways to make `buttons` act like links: [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: My mistake, I didn't understand. What I thought was just formatting code was adding whitespace. My mistake, thanks for the quick response and the helpful link.

Answer (score 2):

Either declare in a CSS file, or directly on the anchor element, a text-decoration of none

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="text-decoration : none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `text-decoration: none;` on your anchor tags that wrapped the button.