# HTML href doesn't redirect to specific href

Tags: html, css, href

I created an `<a>` tag with `href` to redirect to another page. On clicking nothing happens only on the a specific page I'm working on. seems like there is some CSS which bloc the redirect task.

I tried to use `pointer-events` to solve it but nothing happens to.
Any idea about what could be the reason ?

`<button class = "link external" style="pointer-events: auto;" href="chooseproducts.php">test</button>`

Comment: Please change your button to hyperlink (a tag). Also there is no need for pointer events with anchor tag.

Comment: I'm confused at what you're asking. You said you are using an `<a>` tag yet you provide an example with a `<button>` tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341011/making-a-button-thats-a-link-in-html

Answer (score 1):

[The element for creating a link is `<a>`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

There is no `href` attribute for a `<button>` element (which, depending on its `type`, is used to submit forms, reset forms, or attach JS to).

Using [a validator](https://validator.nu/) would have highlighted this error.

Comment: Hi , oh yes i provide a wrong tag for button . i just restart my editor and the a tag works fine. Thanks a lot for your help